# How can I modify an adapter after login?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Heres my setup:

Ember: 1.1.0-beta.1

Ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.2

```
# ON STARTUP
APP.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
  headers: {
    'X-API-TOKEN': localStorage.token
  }
)
```

This works fine if they were already logged in when they refresh...

However...

```
#ON LOGIN FORM SUBMIT ACTION
$.post('/sessions', data).then( (response) =>
  if response.token
    localStorage.token = response.token
    APP.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.reopen(
      headers: {
        'X-API-TOKEN': localStorage.token
      }
    )
  else
    @set('error_message', response.error)
```

The calls are still unauthorized, and the adapter keep trying to pass the old token.

So basically the 'headers' property on the adapter is not updated by the 'reopen' method. Whats the proper way to change the adapter in ember-data?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Once instantiated you should get your adapter from the container.

But since it's not very clear from where you are making the request, try something like this:

```
#ON LOGIN FORM SUBMIT ACTION
$.post('/sessions', data).then( (response) =>
  if response.token
    localStorage.token = response.token

    adapter = APP.__container__.lookup 'adapter:Rest'
    adapter.set('headers', { 'X-API-TOKEN': localStorage.token })

  else
    @set('error_message', response.error)
```

> Note: using `App.__container__` is not recomended for production code depending from where you are making the request it would be more appropriate to get the container in a more clean way.

### Update in response to your last comment

In the case you need access to the container in a controller then:

```
APP.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  ...
  adapter = @get('container').lookup 'adapter:application'
  adapter.set('headers', { 'X-API-TOKEN': localStorage.token })
  ...
```

should get you the adapter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The $.post code is within the LoginController, does that change the answer?

Comment: also it ended up being adapter = APP.__container__.lookup 'adapter:application' but you got me to a working solution...I'm just wondering if there is a more emberish way...I know that using __container__ is supposed to be a no no

Answer (score 2):

Headers can be used as a computed property to support dynamic headers.
You can use the volatile function to set the property into a non-cached mode causing the headers to be recomputed with every request.

```
APP.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(
  headers: function() {
    return {
      'X-API-TOKEN': localStorage.token 
    };
  }.property().volatile()
)
```

URL's:

[toc_headers-customization](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization)

[method_volatile](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html#method_volatile)